# Nestjs Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1"

Tags: nestjs, aws-sdk

Am Working on a nestjs project and trying to list s3 buckets using `aws-sdk` dependency
While running the project, getting below error

```
"type": "Error",
      "message": "Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1",
      "stack":
          Error: connect ENETUNREACH 169.254.169.254:80
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16)
              at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)
      "errno": -4062,
```

I have set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1 in windows environment variable, but still getting the same error.

Do i need to do something else?
please suggest a solution.
Thanks in advance.